# Facebook embed posts are not shown anymore

Tags: javascript, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, embed, mobile-application

I have an application on Cordova written in javascript, I use a facebook javascript sdk library to shown embed posts in the application. For some reason, I started to get the error (see the picture), although the post was being shown before.

What can possibly cause this?

[image]

Comment: As it states the post is either removed or not public did you try any public post

Comment: I have used the same post as before, when it was shown, and its privacy settings are not changed since.